# How to prevent controller invocation when using an Http Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and I use an Http Handler in it.

How can I prevent the site from searching for a controller to invoke after/before the HttpHandler gets invoked?

Now the handler gets invoked and then I get an 404 error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the route in `RegisterRoutes` in global.ascx.cs file like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default1", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{param}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional}, // Parameter defaults
            new[] { "YourProjectName.Controllers" }
        );
```

**Note:**

1. Change `YourProjectName` here.
2. Keep your handler outside of the `Controllers` folder (if it's there) and it should work just fine. Do some more google on routing.